# `npm` busted - how to get past module-not-found, unexpected-token errors

Tags: node.js, npm

I've installed Node and NPM using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

When I tried to run `npm install`, I got an error `Unexpected token '.'`, then a path to a complete log of the run.

I checked the complete log, and unexpected token came from a file that contained only the text
`../workspace/libnpmfund`

That looks a Unix symlink on Windows.

I tried deleting the file and re-installing `libnpmfund`

```sh
npm i -g libnpmfund
```

But the output I get from that is `Cannot find module 'libnpmfund'`.

I tried changing what version of node and npm I was using, to no avail.

How can I fix this? How did I get into this mess?

(FYI there were a bunch of such symlinks and I deleted them all intending to re-install them correctly one by one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under macOS (and apparently this will work under Windows as well), what I did was basically to remove everything under `node_modules`, delete `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, and start from scratch.

It seems that when `npm` is seriously confused to the point that it stops finding its own modules (you cannot install anything since `npm` is broken...), the 'best' alternative seems to be to do everything from the beginning.

This doesn't seem to be a *real* solution, but eventually just a workaround — a quick fix that may be helpful to others having encountered the same issue who attempted to figure out a more obvious solution...

Answer (score 0):

I am using nvm for windows and had the following installed.

Node 15.0.1 and Npm 7.0.3

For some reason, I updated npm to 8.8.0, which then complained that it requires Node 16 or higher.

I used nvm to install the latest version of Node, which was Node 18.1.0, which includes Npm 8.8.0 and I switched over to use this version via nvm.

This is where I ran into the same error, I couldn't update npm or install anything with it.

I managed to resolve the issue by copying all the npm related files from my v15 folder (...\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v15.0.1) over to the v18 folder (...\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.1.0).

Files Copied:
npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd and \node_modules\npm (entire npm folder)

After that, I was good to go again.

I realise that not everyone is going to have a working copy of npm available but I guess the point is that replacing the version of npm that was installed along with node via nvm worked for me.

Obviously npm is broken so try installing it via a script or downloading a zip/tgz.